# Why a php template render in symfony 3.4 is printing http headers?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to move from a messy PHP template structure, with many duplicated code, to [slots](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/PHP.html#working-with-slots) to help us having a similar twig philosophy with the extends.

The problem that we have is that some templates are rendering the HTTP Headers:
[image]

The code for Form/form.html.php is:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TimedPhpEngine    $view
 * @var \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Helper\FormHelper $formHelper
 * @var \Symfony\Component\Templating\Helper\SlotsHelper             $slotsHelper
 * @var \Symfony\Component\Form\FormView                             $form
 */
$formHelper = $view['form'];
$slotsHelper = $view['slots'];

?>
<div class="form-wrapper">
    <?php $slotsHelper->output('form-start', $formHelper->start($form)) ?>
    <?php $slotsHelper->output('form-widget', $formHelper->widget($form)) ?>
    <?php $slotsHelper->output('form-end', $formHelper->end($form)) ?>
</div>
```

And the code for the other template, Form/Order/form.html.php, is

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TimedPhpEngine    $view
 * @var \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Helper\FormHelper $formHelper
 * @var \Symfony\Component\Templating\Helper\SlotsHelper             $slotsHelper
 * @var \Symfony\Component\Form\FormView                             $form
 */
$formHelper = $view['form'];
$slotsHelper = $view['slots'];
$view->extend(':Form:form.html.php');

$slotsHelper->start('form-widget');
echo $formHelper->widget($form);
$slotsHelper->stop();
```

In the Controller, I'm rendering the form as always I've rendered a form:

```
$this->render("Form/Order/form.html.php", ['form' => $orderForm->createView()])
```

If I change this sentence by "returned string", Symfony prints only this "returned string", not the headers.

The form is rendered correctly, but for some reason that I cannot understand, Symfony is printing the HTTP Headers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, after asking I still researching about it and I finally found out why and thanks to this [article](https://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/controller.html#rendering-templates).

I've executed render, but `render` returns the rendered template as `Response`, therefore the HTTP Headers. `renderView` just return the template rendered.

So I've just had to change the line:

```
$this->render("Form/Order/form.html.php", ['form' => $orderForm->createView()])
```

to

```
$this->renderView("Form/Order/form.html.php", ['form' => $orderForm->createView()])
```

Now, it works as expected.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Can you please write up what was wrong and how you fixed it. Linking to outside resources is not considered sufficient for an answer.

Comment: @Sarcoma for sure. Thanks!